# xCode - Referencing specific ViewController as rootViewController in AppDelegate / SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, appdelegate

i have an IB based xCode (13.3, Swift 5) app. The app is connected with Firebase and uses Push-Notifications.

In my main.storyboard (see attached screenhot) my initial vc is a custom splash screen. After that comes a login VC and, if user is logged in, automatically a main tabbar controller witch contains a 5 navigation controllers. The first navigation controller can be understand as "users root view".

**What I'm trying to do is:**
If a user recieves a PushNotificaion I want the app to go directly to a specified vc (1, 2 or 3 in screenshot)
One of them (2) is presented modally, two (1 & 3) are presented by show.

**Here is what i have already:**

1. A custom-url in my project
2. *PushNotification-Class* with data-attributes for the PushNotification's to send them from every point of the app. Part of my payload for the Push-Notification:

```
// ...
"data" :[
     "user" : userName,
     "url" : "app-deeplink:/user/\(userUid)"
]
// ...
```

3. In *AppDelegate*

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
     let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
     let url = URL(string: userInfo["url"] as! String)!
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

4. In **SceneDelegate**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
     guard let urlToOpen = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }
     handleURL(urlToOpen)
}

func handleURL(_ url: URL){
     let section = url.pathComponents[1] // -> is user
     let detail = url.pathComponents[2] // -> is userUid
     if section == "user"{
          navigateToUserVC(user: detail)
     }
     // cutted ... other if's deleted for thread
}
    
func navigateToUserVC(user: String){
     print("TEMP -> here we go to  userVC with user: \(user)")
}
```

**My logic:**
I'm setting a data-attribute for the url with my custom-url.
The receiving user taps on the push-notification and calls therewith the didReceive-Method in AppDelegate.
The didReceive forwards the received data to SceneDelegate. handleURL in SceneDelegate break down the url in parts an calls various functions where the app should go. And here is my problem:

**At this point, how can I instantiate a ViewController and switch to/display it? I've read a lot about changing the actual RootViewController but there are probably problems that there are no more options for the user to reach the navigation elements because the MainTabBarController is then probably gone.**

Screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N69B.jpg)

Thanks in advance for helping
Steven Woodlink

I'm not sure what to do because i have read so many threads but every single one tells different ways or are outdated.